# instance[output.propName].subscribe is not a function resulting from polyfill

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I'm running into a strange issue. I've researched the error, and it generally seems to be related to the use of `@Output` or `EventEmitter`, but that's not the case here.

I get the following error in my application if I have a particular polyfill in place:

```
TypeError: instance[output.propName].subscribe is not a function
    at createDirectiveInstance (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/stuart/localhost/projects/tt-new/work-group/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:12319:71)
    at createViewNodes (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/stuart/localhost/projects/tt-new/work-group/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:13776:38)
    at callViewAction (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/stuart/localhost/projects/tt-new/work-group/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:14210:1)
    at execComponentViewsAction (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/stuart/localhost/projects/tt-new/work-group/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:14119:1)
    at createViewNodes (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/stuart/localhost/projects/tt-new/work-group/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:13804:1)
    at createRootView (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/stuart/localhost/projects/tt-new/work-group/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:13665:1)
    at callWithDebugContext (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/stuart/localhost/projects/tt-new/work-group/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:15090:26)
    at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/stuart/localhost/projects/tt-new/work-group/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:14373:1)
    at ComponentFactory_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/esm5/core.js.ComponentFactory_.create (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/stuart/localhost/projects/tt-new/work-group/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:11260:26)
    at initComponent (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/stuart/localhost/projects/tt-new/work-group/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/testing.js:1137:1)
```

The polyfill is as follows:

```
Object.prototype.clone = function(deep = false) {
    return (deep)
        ? JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this)) // Deep clone - copies object property values in full.
        : Object.assign({}, this);         // Shallow clone - copies property values (including object references rather than object).
};
```

Can anyone help me understand why this might cause an error inside `createDirectiveInstance`? If I comment this code out, the error goes away. It's not simply having a polyfill that causes problems - there's another, which adds `Array.prototype.upsert`, which doesn't cause problems.

Answer (score 119):

I have just faced this issue and checking the code I wrote I discovered that it was caused due to a bad import of the EventEmitter class (done by the autoimport of visual studio code).

You just need to change

```
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';
```

To

```
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
```

And about the error explanation. Angular maps the events as observables, so it has to subscribe to the children components' events and send them to the appropiate components.

Looking for the original package I found its source code on: https://github.com/Gozala/events/blob/master/events.js

And it simply fails because there isn't a method `.suscribe()` in the EventEmitter you have created.

Comment: I'm aware of the issues with this around `EventEmitter`, but that's not the problem I'm having. As I wrote in my question, this is related to a specific polyfill - the error happens when it's present, but not when it's commented out.

Comment: aagh! That was my problem too. Also a VS Code user. Answer was helpful.

Comment: Another stupid mistake I've made with regard to EventEmitters is simply not instantiating them in the component (foo = new EventEmitter())! And this leads to a very similar message in a polyfill, and further down the stack, in vendor.js where the actual statement described in the main error message is found.

Comment: Thanks, it was driving me mad.

Answer (score 0):

First off, it's probably a bad idea to implement an un-optimized clone function, especially when many libraries have implemented it already[1]. Having said that, this answer may be useful if you can't add libraries, or for other people like me looking to extend `Object`.

This seems to be a result of improperly declaring a property on `Object.prototype`.  I'm guessing there's some unmet expectation that `createDirectiveInstance` has when it enumerates `Object.clone` (it probably shouldn't be enumerating it). Instead, use the `Object.defineProperty` method:

```
Object.defineProperty(
  Object.prototype,
  'clone',
  {
    value: function (deep = false) {
      return (deep)
        ? JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this)) // Deep clone - copies object property values in full.
        : Object.assign({}, this);         // Shallow clone - copies property values (including object references rather than object).
    },
    writable: false,
    enumerable: false
  }
);
```

That could be refactored to the following Typescript:

```
function CloneThis(deep = false): any {
  return (deep)
    ? JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this)) // Deep clone - copies object property values in full.
    : Object.assign({}, this);         // Shallow clone - copies property values (including object references rather than object).
}
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'clone',
  <PropertyDescriptor>{
    value: CloneThis,
    writable: false,
    enumerable: false
  }
);
```

However, to get type inference from TypeScript, I think you also need to declare an extension to the global interface for Object:

```
declare global {
  interface Object {
    clone(deep?: boolean): any;
  }
}
```

For more resources on `Object.defineProperty`, see:

- [Mozilla Javascript reference for Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)
- [You Don't Know JS: this & Object Prototypes, Chapter 3](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch3.md#property-descriptors)

[1] Javascript Clone implementations:

- http://ramdajs.com/docs/#clone
- https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#clone
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.clone
- https://github.com/pvorb/clone
- https://github.com/jonschlinkert/shallow-clone

Comment: The question is not whether implementing my own `Object.prototype.clone` is a good idea or not, but why adding one polyfill causes the error, when another doesn't (as mentioned in the question). 

I've done the interface extension, for both of my custom polyfills.

I might give `Object.defineProperty` a try, but even if that works it won't resolve the underlying question.

Comment: If you use `Object.defineProperty`, it definitely works (tested with Angular 5.2.0). Every object inherits from `Object`, of course changing it will have more unintended effects than meddling with `Array`. As mentioned, `createDirectiveInstance` enumerates over the inherited Object property `clone`. On [line 138](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.2.0/packages/core/src/view/provider.ts#L138), `instance[output.propName !].subscribe(` becomes `instance['clone'].subscribe(`. And `instance` only inherits `Object` not `Array`. Just stop creating `Object.prototype.clone` as enumerable.

Comment: This worked for me. Such a shame that it was downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I found a solution that worked for me.

in the project's node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js

```
10768: var /** @type {?} */ subscription = instance[((output.propName))].subscribe(...
```

Somehow it was getting a `propName` called `assign` which is not on the `instance` object. Just put and if statement and make sure it has a subscribe function before calling it. Something like like this:

```
 if (instance[((output.propName))] && typeof instance[((output.propName))].subscribe === 'function'){
            var /** @type {?} */ subscription = instance[((output.propName))].subscribe(eventHandlerClosure(view, /** @type {?} */ ((def.parent)).index, output.eventName)); /** @type {?} */
            ((view.disposables))[def.outputIndex + i] = subscription.unsubscribe.bind(subscription);
        }
```

And you may also need to do a check here:

```
12515: view.disposables[i]();
```

i did this:

```
if (view.disposables[i] && typeof view.disposables[i] === 'function'){
          view.disposables[i]();
}
```

I would not recommend this monkey patch but it worked for me and so far I have not had any errors since. I hope it helps or even aid someone in finding a better solution.

Answer (score -2):

I found you could get this error by accidentally subscribing on an `@Output`-decorated method rather than a property.

For example if you have:

```
  <app-thing (onReady)="...">
  </app-thing>
```

Make sure in the child component you have:

```
  @Output() onReady: Observable<...>
```

or:

```
  @Output() get onReady(): Observable<...> {
    ...
  }
```

**...NOT:**

```
  @Output() onReady(): Observable<...> {
    ...
  }
```

Comment: As mentioned in OP, this error was in a polyfill, and had nothing to do with @Output properties.